# getting an error -25299 attempting to create account and password for proxy

Tags: macos, network, keychain, proxy

I changed the proxy settings with the following code:

```
sudo networksetup -setwebproxy Wi-Fi IP_ADDRESS PORT on USERNAME PASSWORD
```

It does indeed changes settings, but throws an error saying:

```
error -25299 attempting to create account and password for proxy
```

What could be the reason for this? I think it has something to do with `Keychain app`, since after changing proxy in Network tab, I also need to press `Allow/Always allow` when this popup is triggered(right after changing proxy settings). Using sudo command above doesn't manage this popup.

[image]

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Ended up ignoring it.